# Testing API for POST method, got "Unknown error" in response

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, ruby-jmeter

I am new to jmeter and I'm testing API for POST method. I put json request in **Body** & checked the response by using listener as view table tree it shows status as success but i checked in response it shows error message as:

```
{
  "response": {
    "code": 33113,
    "type": "Error",
    "message": "Unknown error"
  }
}
```

But when i tried same API in postman it shows correct success Response with output parameters.

I am passing parameters as :

```
{
    "accessToken" : "35abcs",
    "companyCode" : "abc73",
    "timestamp"   : "1-08-2014",
    "size"        : 10,
    "startIndex"  : 53587
}
```

Comment: Can you show you Http Request in JMeter and the Header manager under it ? Also if you know what 33113 means (ask app team)

Answer (score -1):

TRy adding the header with content type as json.